# How to Globally Use wp_localize_script() Ajax URL

Tags: theme-development, ajax, wp-localize-script

I have added this to my `functions.php` and need to use `ajaxURL` in all of enqueued scripts in the template (instead of enqueuing only one script here

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajaxify_enqueue_scripts' );
function ajaxify_enqueue_scripts() {
   wp_localize_script( 'ajaxify', 'ajaxURL', array('ajax_url' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/app/login.php' ));
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_set_ajaxify', 'set_ajaxify' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_set_ajaxify', 'set_ajaxify' );
```

but when I try to call an ajax method I am getting this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxURL is not defined
```

Is there any way to add  the `ajaxURL` to all scripts?

Comment: What action is `ajaxify_enqueue_scripts` hooked to?

Comment: Hi Milo sorry I just updated the code (forget to add the action). As you can see it is hooked to `'wp_enqueue_scripts'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can conditionally echo the code on only few templates or specific pages. Here is an example:

```
add_action ( 'wp_head', 'my_js_variables' );
function my_js_variables(){
  // for specific page templates
  $current_template =  get_page_template();

  // return if there is no page template, or if the page template is other than template-x1.php or template-x2.php
  if( !isset($current_template) || ( $current_template != 'template-x1.php' && $current_template != 'template-x2.php' ) ){ return; } ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxurl = <?php echo json_encode( admin_url( "admin-ajax.php" ) ); ?>; 
    var ajaxnonce = <?php echo json_encode( wp_create_nonce( "itr_ajax_nonce" ) ); ?>;
    var myarray = <?php echo json_encode( array(
         'foo' => 'bar',
         'available' => TRUE,
         'ship' => array( 1, 2, 3, ),
       ) ); ?>
  </script>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To have the ajaxurl variable available on the frontend the easiest way is to add this snippet to you theme’s function.php file:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'myplugin_ajaxurl');
function myplugin_ajaxurl() {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
           var ajaxurl = "' . admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . '";
         </script>';
}
```

This get the url of the ajax submission page and creates a variable in the head of the HTML with it. Now ‘ajaxurl’ is available in your theme so you can start making it more modern and dynamic.

Comment: Thanks a lots vikrant but I have two questions now, 1- is there any way to add this to specific head instead of all head? 2- I have seen some example at this methos using `var ajaxnonce = '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( "itr_ajax_nonce" ); ?>';` can you please let me know what is the usage of `nonce` here?

Comment: i send some example please check . This code help for you .